# What's the correct way to count total number when iterating a generator?

Tags: python

I'm always told that the `enumerate` built-in can be used when you need to count number and iterate at the same time.

For example this is a common idiom in Python (function `gen` returns a generator):

```
for index, item in enumerate(gen()):
    # Do something with item

# get the numbers consumed from generator
print("% number of items processed" % (index+1,))
```

But if the generator returns nothing? e.g. `enumerate(range(0))`, the `index` variable will be undefined.

We can define `index` variable before the for loop, but is there any more pythonic solution that I didn't aware of?

Comment: I'm not sure what's so un-Pythonic about initializing a variable that you are intending to use later.

Answer (score 5):

`enumerate(gen(), start=1)` will make `index` start counting from 1, removing the need for `index+1`. Otherwise, I think what you have is already Pythonic.

```
index = 0
for index, item in enumerate(gen(), start=1):
    # Do something with item

print("%d number of items processed" % (index,))
```

Comment: you could use `index = -1`, drop `start=1`, and print `(index + 1,)` if `index` is required inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending to use the `index` again, then just initialize it above your `for` loop like you said. There's nothing "un-Pythonic" about this.

If you are not sure if `index` will be defined, you can always use try/except:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function  # for Python 2 compatibility
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> for i, j in enumerate(range(0)):
...   pass
... 
>>> try:
...   print(i)
... except NameError:
...   print('i was not defined', file=sys.stderr)
... 
i was not defined
```